# Rails 3 Activity Tracker Database Management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I recently added User activity tracking functionality to my application which tracks user interaction with several models, and several different actions within each model.

```
class User

  has_many :activities, :order => 'created_at desc'     

  def log_activity(object, type)
    activities.create(:subject_type => object.class.name, :subject_id => object.id, :subject_action_type => type)
  end 

end
```

Now I call this method after a User creates/updates/deletes various objects and display this activity on the user profile. I imagine that after a while the Activities table will contain so many records it's going to get to the point where it effects load times. I was wondering what a good implementation would be to manage this in a user-friendly way and keep my database running smoothly.

I was thinking of setting up some kind of scheduled task that cleans up old records after x amount of time. Perhaps you can give some advice as to how to accomplish this or recommend an even better solution?

I'm using **PostgreSQL** as my database of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `activities` lazy loads so it won't pull in all of the associated activities unless you ask for them. So when you say this:

```
activities.create(...)
```

All you're doing to the database is a single INSERT: there is no `select * from activities where ...` to build `activities`, there's just the INSERT from the `create` call.

So you don't have anything to worry about from your `log_activity` method.

If you want to limit the size of your `activities` table then a simple:

```
Activity.connection.execute("delete from activities where created_at < now() - interval '10 days'")
```

every now and then should be fine to clear out the dead wood. The `'10 days'` is, of course, just for illustration.

Comment: I suppose I could always just manually run the query. If it gets to be too much of a hassle I'm sure it isn't too much hassle to just automate the process.